# Response code 418 when trying to web scrape the API

Tags: python-3.x, api, web-scraping

I am trying to get the data from API: https://www.techinasia.com/wp-json/techinasia/2.0/posts.
But i get the HTTP response as 418.
What can be the possible way to resolve it?

````
url ='https://www.techinasia.com/wp-json/techinasia/2.0/posts'
response = requests.get(url)
print(type(response),response)```

Output: 
<class 'requests.models.Response'> <Response [418]>
````

Comment: Using headers should fix the issue you are having.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Passing a user-agent of your choosing is enough to get the response. Request invokes an HTTP get request, but sometimes the server requires a user-agent, partial/complete headers, parameters or cookies to authenticate the request.

In this case, all you need is a user-agent, infact you don't even need to pass a valid user-agent.

### Code Example

```
import requests

headers = {
   'User-Agent': 'M',
   }

requests.get('https://www.techinasia.com/wp-json/techinasia/2.0/posts',headers=headers)
```

### Output

```
<Response [200]>
```

You have to specify in the HTTP request the headers, the get method of requests, gives you an argument to do just that, `headers`. The headers argument should contain a python dictionary.

Comment: I tried executing with passing of User-Agent , but still receiving Response code [418]. I am using Anaconda Jupyter Notebook.

Comment: Ah! sorry I forgot to add requests.get(url,headers=headers), check updated code.